# C++: no match for call to '(concat) (std::string&)'

Tags: c++, string, class, operator-overloading

I have been trying to write this C++ program to concatenate strings taken as input from the user using Operator Overloading on the operator(+=). And I have defined the constructor to initialize the objects as well as to take string as an argument. But it still shows the error

> error: no match for call to '(concat) (std::string&)'|

Here's the code for the 3 files=>
**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "concat.h"
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
concat ob[10];
concat result;
int i;
string ip;
cout<<"Enter the strings upto 10 in different lines.. \n";
for(i=0;i<(sizeof(ob)/sizeof(ob[0]));i++){
    cin>>ip;
    ob[i](ip);
}

while(i!=0){
    result += ob[i++];
}
cout<<result.input;
}
```

**concat.h**

```
#ifndef CONCAT_H
#define CONCAT_H
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class concat
{
public:
    string input;
    concat();
    concat(string ip);
    concat operator+=(concat );

};

#endif // CONCAT_H
```

**concat.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "concat.h"
#include<string>
using namespace std;

concat::concat(){
}
concat::concat(string ip)
:input(ip)
{
}
concat concat::operator+=(concat ipObj){
    this->input += ipObj.input;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: In your initialization of the `concat` objects you use `ob[i](ip)`. To do this you'd need a function call operator (i.e. `operator()(string const&)` on your `concat` type. You probably wanted to write `ob[i] = concat(ip)` or `ob[i] = ip` (as the constructor from `std::string` is implicit this approach should work, too). Also, **always** check that your input was successful before using it: `if (std::cin >> ip) { ... }`

Comment: I did try to use the second approach to change, ob[i](ip) to ob[i] = concat(ip) as well as ob[i]= ip. It's executing without errors but after I give the input, the program crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how your `concat` class prototype should look:

```
class concat
{
public:
    string input;
    concat() = default;
    concat& operator+=(const concat&);

    // assignment operator
    concat& operator=(const string& str) {  
        input = str;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

And then use `ob[i] = ip;` instead of `ob[i](ip)`.

Also, your program crashes because you wrote `result += ob[i++];` 
instead of `result += ob[--i];`

Comment: It crashed even after that.

Comment: Opps, sorry, I changed from `i--` to `--i`.

Comment: It is because `i == sizeof(ob)/sizeof(ob[0])` at that moment and it is `max index + 1` resulting to out of range exception. Because `i--` first gets the value of `i` and decrements only after that

Comment: I changed the while loop to for loop and used i++ to increment it in the order the input is given. And replaced ob[i](ip) to ob[i]=(ip);. It solved the problem.

Comment: Still i dont think that `class` = `string` is best practice

Comment: Yeah, I didn't exactly go with that prototype entirely either. But it helped me figure it out how it worked and, when I tried to use "move", it said it couldn't be found in std.

Comment: @ Filip Kočica, Moreover, I would even say that operator overloading is not the best practice. But looks like Harshit is just studying C++ so that is ok.